# Initialising objects in a fragment of viewpager

Tags: android, performance, android-fragments

I have an application which initiates from a viewPager somewhat like snapchat for reference. Based on the current pattern, which is: 
Initialising all the content on fragment is created; the UI thread is being clogged and the application takes a considerable amount of time to initiate.

How do I do it? Since I need to work on these objects on the main thread itself.

Answer (score 1):

In your fragment create a static instance like this

```
    public static FragmentSample newInstance(Datamodel Model) {
    FragmentBatch fragment = new FragmentBatch();
    Bundle args  = new Bundle();
    args.putParcelable("extra",Model);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
```

and initialize it in the activity's section adapter

```
 public class SampleActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

/**
 * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
 * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
 * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
 * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
 * may be best to switch to a
 * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
 */
private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

/**
 * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
 */
private ViewPager mViewPager;
Datamodel datamodel;
int batchCount;
List<Datamodel > datamodels;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_weight_record);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
    datamodels= new ArrayList<>();
    datamodels.add(new Datamodel ("Neoperene", "skyperene", "", "22w441",1,"+/-1%",""));
    datamodels.add(new Datamodel ("Neoperene", "skyperene", "", "22w442",2,"+/-1%",""));
    datamodels.add(new Datamodel ("Neoperene", "skyperene", "", "22w443",3,"+/-1%",""));

}



 public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).

        switch(position){
            case 0:                    
                return FragmentSample.newInstance(Datamodel.get(0));
            case 1:
                return FragmentBatch.newInstance(Datamodel.get(1));
            default:
                return FragmentBatch.newInstance(Datamodel.get(0));
  }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "SECTION 1";
            case 1:
                return "SECTION 2";
            case 2:
                return "SECTION 3";
        }
        return null;
    }
}
}
```